# Put [stack-exchange] in the stack for tag exchanges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, burninate-request

It looks like the [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) tag (later renamed to [stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange)) is a holdover from the pre-split days when this site was called Meta Stack Overflow and also served as the meta site for Stack Overflow (in addition to its current purpose). It was intended to disambiguate questions about the SE network as a whole from questions specifically about Stack Overflow ([stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow)). It has nearly 1,500 uses, so it's too big to clean up manually. It looks like people are still using it on new questions, and I just saw a suggested edit that *only* added this tag. Since **all** questions here should be about Stack Exchange, can we burninate this<strike>, the ultimate</strike> meta tag?

Comment: What about those that want to talk about the company?

Comment: @random Those people should stop using that tag too.

Comment: So you wouldn't want to differentiate talk between the network and community and the overlords and their machinations?

Comment: @random We could do that, but probably with a different tag. This one is too ambiguous. Maybe a [company] or [businessing] tag? (In seriousness though, [stack-exchange-inc] would probably work for that.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard but [meta-stack-exchange] did/does exist.  It is a synonym of [meta] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta/synonyms)

Comment: @psubsee2003 That explains why I couldn't find it! I knew it had to be here somewhere. Edited.

Answer (score 18):

I have to agree.

Looking at the questions from the list in the stack exchange tag, there are none where the tag adds context, nor where removing the tag would remove context.

Moreover, the topicality of "Stack Exchange" is inherent in the "Meta Stack Exchange" site as Bill notes in this question.  In my opinion it makes sense to remove this tag, and I defer to this person:

[image]